# AWS SDK for PHP using S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

We are using the **AWS SDK for PHP**. We use a call similar to this to make the connection to our custom S3 service:

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
   'region' => 'us-east-1',
   'version' => '2006-03-01',
   'credentials'=> [
      'key' => 'KEY',
      'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY'
    ]
]);
```

In order to get the files to the custom S3 service we use, in the **enpoints.json.php** file, the hostname for **us-east-1** under **aws-global** is modified (see *OUR_CUSTOM_HOSTNAME*):

```
], ], 'aws-global' => ['credentialScope' => ['region' => 'us-east-1', ], 'hostname' => 'OUR_CUSTOM_HOSTNAME', 'signatureVersions' => ['s3', 's3v4', ], ], 'ca-central-1' => ['variants' => [
        ['hostname' => 's3-fips.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'tags' => ['fips', ], ],
        ['hostname' => 's3-fips.dualstack.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'tags' => ['dualstack', 'fips', ], ],
        ['hostname' => 's3.dualstack.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'tags' => ['dualstack', ], ],
```

So in our situation, we have another separate service which is also s3 based, and I need to send a backup copy of each file to that service right after it is sent it to our primary location. My first thought is to re-point another region's hostname in the **endpoints.json.php** file so I could do something like this:

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
   'region' => 'some_other_region_with_alternate_hostname',
   'version' => '2006-03-01',
   'credentials'=> [
      'key' => 'KEY',
      'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY'
    ]
]);
```

... but I can not figure out the proper place to do that as it's not clear which part of the array in that file needs to be changed. For example, if I wanted to repoint **us-west-1** to a different hostname so I could do this ...

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
   'region' => 'us-west-1',
   'version' => '2006-03-01',
   'credentials'=> [
      'key' => 'KEY',
      'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY'
    ]
]);
```

Where would I do that in the **enpoints.json.php** file exactly?

Alternatively, is there a way to do something in the order of this?

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
   'hostname' => 'my_custom_hostname',
   'version' => '2006-03-01',
   'credentials'=> [
      'key' => 'KEY',
      'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY'
    ]
]);
```

**UPDATE**

To clarify:

1. Primary service is objects.liquidweb.com
2. Backup is s3.wasabisys.com

So I experimented with changing this line in the **enpoints.json.php** file (hostname to s3.wasabisys.com):

```
], ], 'us-west-1' => ['hostname' => 's3.wasabisys.com', 'signatureVersions' => ['s3', 's3v4', ], 'variants' => [
    ['hostname' => 's3-fips.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'tags' => ['dualstack', 'fips', ], ],
    ['hostname' => 's3-fips.us-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'tags' => ['fips', ], ],
    ['hostname' => 's3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'tags' => ['dualstack', ], ],
```

It is definitely getting the correct bucket (*saasawx-livesystem-backups*) and hostname (*s3.wasabisys.com*) and file location, but I get this error: **AuthorizationHeaderMalformed (client): The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-west-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1'**

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://saasawx-livesystem-backups.s3.wasabisys.com/saasawxdev/frep/s22.png"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://saasawx-livesystem-backups.s3.wasabisys.com/saasawxdev/frep/s22.png` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header (truncated...)
AuthorizationHeaderMalformed (client): The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-west-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-1' - <Region>us-east-1</Region><RequestId>B05C214FCEF1FC90</RequestId><HostId>MCg8Kc+GPS87xYb9yG9LXWSlXKJsmeetWjeZpcF8sua21qY2FZoTKs6E6Qyt4qDH5oIkEjtPU9zL</HostId></Error>
```

For some additional context, I create the initial S3 client for the primary location in global space so other functions can access it in this php file like this:

```
// INITIALIZE S3 CLIENT ********************
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials'=> [
        'key' => 'KEY',
        'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY'
    ]
]);
```

... then the function that writes the file to our primary location uses this client, and works just fine:

```
function cdn__writeFile( $in_file_to_copy, $in_cdn_filename ) {
    global $s3Client, $bucket;
    // write the file etc ...

}
```

However, the backup function - since it is using a different S3 location, does not use the global $s3Client, but instead uses a local version like this:

```
function cdn__writeWasabiBackupFile( $in_file_to_copy, $in_cdn_filename ) {
    
    // INITIALIZE S3 CLIENT (WASABI SERVICE) ********************
    $s3WasabiClient = new S3Client([
        'region' => 'us-west-1',
        'version' => '2006-03-01',
        'credentials'=> [
            'key' => 'KEY',
            'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY'
        ]
    ]);
    // write the file etc ...
}
```

The buckets are different as well, as I saw some mentions of the buckets needing to be different. My initial thought is maybe I cannot use 2 separate regions or 2 separate services in a single script?

Comment: We don't know how your custom service reads the parameters from enpoints.json.php. You might want to add this in your question so we can understand it better and help you.